# Make Null Values Display As Blank While Still Maintaining Number Format In MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am writing a query in MS Access where I pull numerical data from a table that includes null values, and I am trying to make the null values appear as blanks (or any non-numerical string would be fine), yet still be able to include them in functions as if they were zero.

Originally my query looked like

```
Select CDbl(Nz([tbl.column],"")) AS Alias
```

Which made nulls appear as errors and didn't allow me to include them in sum functions.

Now the code I am using is

```
Select CDbl(Nz([tbl.column],0)) AS Alias
```

Which allows me to include them in sums but they are displayed as 0s.

I have also already tried setting the field properties to be number with default value as blank, but this has not helped either.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to replace null with zero:

```
SELECT IIf(IsNull([tbl.column]),0,[tbl.column]) AS Alias
FROM tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not that complicated. If you want to display "blanks" for Null, that's the default behaviour:

```
Select tbl.column AS Alias
```

If you for some processing wish to handle the Null values as zero, use a separate alias:

```
Select Nz(tbl.column, 0) AS NumericAlias
```

But for *Sum* it makes no difference; Null is ignored, and zero adds nothing to the sum.